# How can I trim mp3 file in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, mp3, windows-10-universal, trim

I want to trim a music file(mp3) in my UWP win 10 app. I try using Naudio but it's not working in my app, so how can i do it ?

Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to trim a mp3 file, you can use [**Windows.Media.Editing namespace**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.editing.aspx), especially **[MediaClip class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.editing.mediaclip.aspx)**.

By default, this class is used for clipping from a video file. But we can also use this class to trim mp3 file by setting [**MediaEncodingProfile**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.mediaproperties.mediaencodingprofile.aspx) in **[MediaComposition.RenderToFileAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn652696.aspx)** method while rendering.

Following is a simple sample:

```
var openPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.MusicLibrary;
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp3");

var pickedFile = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
if (pickedFile != null)
{
    //Created encoding profile based on the picked file
    var encodingProfile = await MediaEncodingProfile.CreateFromFileAsync(pickedFile);

    var clip = await MediaClip.CreateFromFileAsync(pickedFile);

    // Trim the front and back 25% from the clip
    clip.TrimTimeFromStart = new TimeSpan((long)(clip.OriginalDuration.Ticks * 0.25));
    clip.TrimTimeFromEnd = new TimeSpan((long)(clip.OriginalDuration.Ticks * 0.25));

    var composition = new MediaComposition();
    composition.Clips.Add(clip);

    var savePicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileSavePicker();
    savePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.MusicLibrary;
    savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("MP3 files", new List<string>() { ".mp3" });
    savePicker.SuggestedFileName = "TrimmedClip.mp3";

    StorageFile file = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();
    if (file != null)
    {
        //Save to file using original encoding profile
        var result = await composition.RenderToFileAsync(file, MediaTrimmingPreference.Precise, encodingProfile);

        if (result != Windows.Media.Transcoding.TranscodeFailureReason.None)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Saving was unsuccessful");
        }
        else
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Trimmed clip saved to file");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tks you very much ! You save my time, i spent 1 day with it ! Tks you so much !